# Rearranging numbers of an array like a wave

Tags: java, programming-challenge, interview-questions

> Given an array of integers, sort the array into a wave like array and
>   return it, In other words, arrange the elements into a sequence such
>   that a1 >= a2 <= a3 >= a4 <= a5.....
>
> #### Example
>
> Given `[1, 2, 3, 4]`
>
> One possible answer: `[2, 1, 4, 3]`
>   Another possible answer : `[4, 1, 3, 2]`
>
> NOTE: If there are multiple answers possible, return the one thats
>   lexicographically smallest.  So, in example case, you will return `[2, 1, 4, 3]`

My approach:

```
public class Solution {
    public ArrayList<Integer> wave(ArrayList<Integer> A) {

        Collections.sort(A);
        int swap1, swap2,temp1,temp2;
        //We will have to swap all the odd numbered elements with the even numbered elements
        //such that all numbers with a gap 0f 1 are sorted
        for( swap1= 0, swap2 = swap1 + 1; swap1 <= A.size()- 2; swap1 = swap1+2,swap2 = swap2+2 )
            {
                //Check if swap1 reaches last element
                if( (swap1 == A.size() - 1) || (swap2 == A.size()) )
                    break;
                else
                    {
                        temp1 = A.get(swap1);
                        temp2 = A.get(swap2);
                        A.set(swap1,temp2);
                        A.set(swap2, temp1);
                    }
            }
        return A;
    }
}
```

I have the following questions regarding my code:

1. How can I further optimize my code?  (I am unable to solve these questions within the prescribed time limit. What can I do?)
2. Is there any better approach to do this question?
3. Have I violated any convention in coding?
4. Are there any redundancies in my approach?

[Reference](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/wave-array/)

Answer (score 1):

Few observations.

1. You don't need to maintain `swap2` separately, it is always `swap1 + 1`, so can be simply declared inside the loop's body.
2. Your boundaries check inside the loop body is redundant, loop condition alone is enough.
3. You're probably performing too many int-to-Integer and back conversions. Even more, the question deals with arrays, you don't need to pre-convert the argument into a list. Accept, process and return an array of plain ints.

Comment: You are correct about the redundancy of variables. I could do it with swap1 alone. I had received the input as an arrayList of integers, so I am not converting it to an integer array.  Thanks for the advice. Could you also give some advice regarding 4 and 5?

Comment: See 2. in my response concerning boundaries. As 5. can you specify what exactly you mean? Are 'there questions' numbers 1) through 4)? Too broad.

Comment: And for a better approach, technically, a wave array could have been built faster than NlogN if not for the smallest solution requirement.

Comment: By 5, I meant that I was unable to solve a particular interview question within a time limit. What can I do for this kind of problem?

Comment: Practice. When you face a problem, you need to a) formalize it; b) decompose into elementary pieces trivially solvable; c) construct a valid solution of those pieces. This looks like a reasonable strategy to solve problems in a given time frame. Something like "Learn kung fu," but more detailed.